# Writing a program that finds perfect numbers - error

Tags: python, math, compiler-errors, listiterator

I'm working on a program that finds perfect numbers (i.e., 6, because its factors, 1, 2, and 3, add up to itself). My code is

```
k=2
mprim = []
mprimk = []
pnum = []

def isprime(n):
    """Returns True if n is prime."""
    if n == 2:
        return True
    if n == 3:
        return True
    if n % 2 == 0:
        return False
    if n % 3 == 0:
        return False

    i = 5
    w = 2

    while i * i <= n:
        if n % i == 0:
            return False

        i += w
        w = 6 - w

    return True

def mprime(k):
    while k < 50:
        check = (2**k)-1
        if isprime(check) == True:
            mprim.append(check)
            mprimk.append(k)
            print check
            k+=1
        else:
            k+=1

mprime(k)

def isperf(lst):
    for i in lst:
        prm = (((2**i)-1)(2**i))/(2)
        pnum.append(prm)

isperf(mprimk)

print pnum
```

The first part, that checks if a number is prime, and produces *mercenne primes*, is working alright. Its the second part I'm having trouble with. I have read that if `2^k - 1` is prime, then `((2^k - 1)(2^k))/2` is a *perfect number*, so I am using that formula.

The error it gives is

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "python", line 47, in <module>
  File "python", line 44, in isperf
TypeError: 'int' object is not callable
```

Line 47 is `isperf(mprimk)` and line 44 is `prm = (((2**i)-1)(2**i))/(2)`. Any assistance would be appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: So what's with the parens around `2` in your denominator?

Comment: Concatenation is not multiplication in Python. You need to actually write out the `*` signs.

Comment: `prm = (((2**i)-1)*(2**i))/(2)` it gives correct output.

Comment: For a fast way of testing Mersenne primes, and hence calculating even perfect numbers, please see [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/40631767/4014959).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error clearly states that you are trying to call an int type, which isn't callable.

In practice it means you trying to do something like `123()`

And code responsible for it is `((2**i)-1)(2**i)` because you forgot `*` and it should be `(((2**i)-1)*(2**i))/(2)`