# my program shows unexpected token error. why?

Tags: python

the program needs to return true if the factors of n other than n sum up to n. i need to use the function name during runtime. when i input

```
factors(45)
```

it shows that there is an unexpexted token error. please check what is wrong with the program.

```
def factors(n):#unexpected token error
 factorlist = []
 for i in range(1,n):
  if n%i == 0:
    factorlist = factorlist + [i]
 return(factorlist)
def perfect(n):
 if sum(factorlist) == n:
  return(True)
 else :
  return(False)
```

Comment: `factorlist` not referenced in `perfect(n)` function. May be you wanted `factorlist = factors(n)` ?

Comment: can u do the correction in the program. i am not able to get it. im just beginning to learn python. please

Comment: `45` is not perfect number . so, it returns `False`.

Comment: People have answered below. Use one the answers ;)

Comment: FWIW, this approach is ok to test if small number are perfect, but it gets very slow if you want to search for larger ones. If you want to generate even perfect numbers, you can do that fairly quickly via their relationship with Mersenne primes (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40631767/4014959)). If you want to see if any odd perfect numbers exist, then (as far as we know) you have to add the factors, but there are ways to make it more efficient than a simple brute-force search.

Comment: are you trying to give input on the command line or in the code?

Comment: like, during execution

Comment: Are you using Python 3? If so, to read a number from the user at runtime you can do `n = int(input('Enter number '))`.

Answer (score 1):

You do not call `factors(n)` into the `perfect(n)` function. So, you have to use
`factorlist = factors(n)` into the `perfect(n)` function.

and then try this way :

```
def factors(n):
  factorlist = []
  for i in range(1, n):
    if n % i == 0:
      factorlist = factorlist + [i]
  return (factorlist)


def perfect(n):
  factorlist = factors(n)  # use this line
  if sum(factorlist) == n:
    return (True)
  else:
    return (False)

print(perfect(45)) # Ouput : False
```

Comment: Copy my code and run in the compiler. I think, this code is right and there is no bug.

Answer (score 0):

Try :

```
def factors(n):
    factorlist = []
    for i in range(1,n):
        if n%i == 0:
            factorlist = factorlist + [i]
    print factorlist
    return factorlist

def perfect(n):
    factorlist = factors(n)
    if sum(factorlist) == n:
        return True
    else :
        return False

n = int(raw_input('Enter the number: '))
print(perfect(n))
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: it did not work. same error, how to use an argument in a function?

Comment: @ Benetha, both mine and Md. Rezwanul Haque answers are working and giving output, please try once again. Or post the exact error and code you are trying.

Comment: i need to input the number for what sum has to be calculated only during runtime. how should i change the print command

Comment: you can  use "raw_input" to input values dynamically , see my updated answer

Comment: the runtime command should be>>> perfect(28)                                      true

Comment: python your_filename.py

Comment: no need for that the raw_input will ask you to input the number in the command line, just input and you will get the result. I have attached the screenshot of my command line in my answer.

Comment: it works perfect, but i am forced to use the funtion in the runtime. can u help ?